# Database parent relation to child relation problem

Tags: sql

I have a database for multi shop. Shop has many items like dress, food, cosmetics etc.
So for every type of item their is a table for store details like.

**Dress**: id, name, size, price, color, item_id

**Food**: id, name, type, price, exipry date, item_id

**Cosmetic**: id, type, price, gender, item_id

**Item**: id, tag, store_id

*Store*: id, name

Here item has OneToOne relation with Dress, Food, Cosmetic etc.
Store has OneToMany relation with item.

Now I want to fetch only item like Dress and Food only for a store. But don't understand how to query.
Now I am thinking to store a enum into item for tables like enum(Food, Cosmetic ...). Then fetch items by Dress with join Dress table and sperately fetch for food.

In their any way to change the database without this so that I can query better way. Is database design is bad that's why I am facing problem ? Any better way ?

Comment: What is the relation between Item and the other tables?

Comment: @Scratte updated

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. It is unclear what you mean by *I want to fetch only item like Dress and Food only for a store*

Comment: It looks like you will have to use UNION to fetch all items from a store.

Comment: Guys wait a bit I am updating

Answer (score 0):

I think that, if you can, you should simplify the data model.

1. Table: Store, containing the store id, name, address and any other information you need
2. Table: ItemType, containing item type id, item code, text description (basically a list of labels of types of items you can sell. Making this table instead of a new table for each type will make it easier on you when the stores add a new item type later
3. Table: Item, containing the a primary key id and the following foreign keys (store id, item type id), and then all your standard information. Price, name of the item, description

Then if you want to get items for one store, you select * from Item where store_id in (select id from Store where name = 'MyStore').
If you want to get all of the cosmetics from one store, it's select * from Item where store_id in (select id from Store where name = 'MyStore') and itemType_id in (select id from ItemType where code = 'cosmetics')

This will make maintenance a lot easier in the future when the item catalog changes, since it means you only need to add a row to ItemType before you can add new items. Same thing if you add a new store.